# Pipenv installed packages on environment (Pipenv file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

About the Pipfile that pipenv generates: when I run `pipenv shell` in a specific folder, the virtual environment works just fine, and everything I install in there works fine as well, but the **Pipfile doesn't seem to be updating with the packages I'm installing**. When I check the dependency tree with `pipenv graph`, it shows all the dependencies I've been using. Is there something I'm missing with how pipenv works?

Note:

Whenever I want to create a new env i follow these steps:

```
mkdir app
cd app
pipenv shell
pip install <somepackage>
touch main.py # (add my code)
python main.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have to install packages using the command `pipenv install [package]`** in order for `pipenv` to create/update the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files.

As you already installed the dependencies with `pip`, you can run `pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt && pipenv install -r requirements.txt` and it will create or update the aforementioned files for you. *It is best, though, that you declare each package you want because this method also writes each package dependencies on these files.*

[Read more here](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/)